# How can I pass String value from EditText In Android Activity to Python Script and also retrieve the result from a function in the python script?

Tags: python, android

How can I pass String value from EditText In Android Activity to Python Script
 and also make the activity able to retrieve the String result from a function in the python script 
such as displaying the retrieved String in TextView ?

And my python script is complex script  as it needs importing another scripts inside it which one of them connects to sqlite database .

I want to put the scripts in assets folder in Android or in res/raw folder and I don't want the android application to need internet , I want all things embedded in the app .

simple example for this matter is

```
myscript.py


def addTwoNbrs(x,y):
return x+y
```

and in android activity

```java
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
final EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
final TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
            int x = new Integer(et1.getText().toString());
            int y = new Integer(et2.getText().toString());
            // How to call python script with these 2 parameters x , y to calculate
            int z=  // return the result from the script

            }
});
```

Comment: Well, first you would need an in-process Python script interpreter for Android.  As far as I'm aware, no such thing exists.  There have been a few attempts to create one, but none of the projects have ever been completed.

Comment: thanks , so android_python27 or sl4a as i serached before in them
don't have any solution to this issue , isn't it ?

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: i am sorry , i asked already in stackoverflow but no one answered and before i ask here i found already some technical questions here but if it is not allowed i am sorry

Comment: @islamislam Stack Overflow and Programmers.SE have different scopes. P.SE is for questions regarding software engineering, architecture and design patterns.  The type of thing that you tend to think about before you start writing code.  On the other hand, Stack Overflow is for the "here is some code that isn't working the way I want it to" which you have here. Just because someone didn't answer on Stack Overflow doesn't mean that it is a question appropriate to ask on Programmers.SE.